# R: replacing + within string with -

Tags: r

I have a string:

```
string1 <- "9876442+123456"
```

and I would like to replace the + sign with a - sign

```
string2 <- "9876442-123456"
```

However when I tried:

```
string2 <-gsub("+", "-", string1)
```

I got

```
"-9-8-7-6-4-4-2-+-1-2-3-4-5-6-"
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `gsub("\\+", "-", string1)`

Comment: Here is another link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965949/how-to-replace-using-gsub-function-in-r/43966419#43966419

Comment: Thank yo so much.